# How to test export function with Karma-Jasmine in Angular4

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

It is my first question here, I hope to do well...

I am a begginer doing unit tests with Karma-Jasmine in Angular and I just found a case that I do not know how to resolve it.

I have a .ts file that looks like this:

example.constants.ts

This file have a function that generate a random ID. Here is my code:

```
export function generateUid(separator: string) {
...
}
```

I am trying to do a test of this function because i need cover it. So i decided to create a file *example.constants.spec.ts*. It looks like this

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { generateUid } from './example.constants';

describe('ExampleConstants generateUid', () => {

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: []
    });
});

it('should check if Uid is generated',
    () => {
        expect(0).toBe(0);
});

});
```

The problem is not about how to cover if the function work well. The problem is about this test does not appear when I run *ng test --code-coverage*. I have been working with components and services unit tests but it is the first time that i want to do a test about an export function. This function not have associated component. It is declare in example.constants.ts like an export function.

Could you help me to do this unit test about an export function?

Regards.

Comment: Did you ever managed to do this? I also want to test an exported function.

Comment: I did not get the solution for this question.

Comment: So the test is not executed if you run ng test (independent on code-coverage or not)? If that's the case, could you please share your ts-config.spec.ts and your folder structure please, so it's possible to see where this file is located within the project structure?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to configure testing modules for this scenario. You can test it just like normal functions

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { generateUid } from './example.constants';

describe('ExampleConstants generateUid', () => {

it('should check if Uid is generated',
    () => {
     generateUid('-').toBeDefined();
});

});
```